# Custom Cursor Adapter Error When Running, Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat

**I have updated my post with the changes, I inserted the '_id', and it is all working as it should**

I hope someone can help with my problem as I am quite new to android and java. I have created an app that uses an SQLite database, I am using a custom cursor adapter to print out one line of the database along with 2 buttons and a editText. I think I have the right code but when I try and run the app I am getting an IllegalArgumentException, I have been looking through this forum for a few days now and I am still very stuck. If anyone could point out my error and help me fix it would be great!

This is my main activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.pinchtapzoom.R;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

private CustomCursorAdapter customAdapter;
//private com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter databaseHelper;
public ListView list1;

com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);
//CustomCursorAdapter c = new CustomCursorAdapter(this,c);

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

    list1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.data_list);
    db.open();


    Button addBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add);
    addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, addassignment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button deleteBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Delete.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    Button updateBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.update);
    updateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, Update.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


    try {
        String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/AssignmentDB";
        File f = new File(destPath);
        if (!f.exists()) {
            CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"),
                    new FileOutputStream(destPath));
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


   new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Log.d("test", "customadapter is " + customAdapter.toString());
            //Log.d("test", "databaseHelper is " + databaseHelper.toString());
            customAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(MyActivity.this, db.getAllRecords());
            list1.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        }
    });


}

private class DBAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //private ArrayList<>

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        return null;
    }

}

public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream)
        throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
}
```

This is my database class

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_ITEM = "item";
public static final String KEY_LITRES = "litres";
private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DripDrop";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "assignments";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table if not exists assignments (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                + "item VARCHAR not null, litres date );";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        try {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---
public void close()
{
    DBHelper.close();
}

//---insert a record into the database---
public long insertRecord(String item, String litres)
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_ITEM, item);
    initialValues.put(KEY_LITRES, litres);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

//---deletes a particular record---
public boolean deleteContact(long rowId)
{
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
}

//---retrieves all the records---
public Cursor getAllRecords()
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_ITEM,
            KEY_LITRES}, null, null,null, null, null);
}



//---retrieves a particular record---
public Cursor getRecord(long rowId) throws SQLException
{
    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_ITEM, KEY_LITRES},
                    KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

//---updates a record---
public boolean updateRecord(String item, String litres)
{
    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+DATABASE_TABLE+" SET "+KEY_LITRES+"='"+litres+"' WHERE "+KEY_ITEM+"='"+item+"'");
    return true;
}
}
```

This is my custom cursor class
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import com.pinchtapzoom.R;

```
public class CustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

public CustomCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    // when the view will be created for first time,
    // we need to tell the adapters, how each item will look
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // here we are setting our data
    // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

    TextView textViewPersonName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item1);
    textViewPersonName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));

}
}
```

And this is the logcat error that I am getting when I run the app

```
    4501-4501/com.example.rory.dbtest E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.rory.dbtest, PID: 4501
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
        at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
        at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:120)
        at com.example.rory.dbtest.CustomCursorAdapter.<init>(CustomCursorAdapter.java:19)
        at com.example.rory.dbtest.MyActivity$4.run(MyActivity.java:94)
```

Comment: column name "_id" is expected and "id" table has, change the create table query to have "_id"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is change the id column to _id because when using a custom cursor adapter it requires the column _id to be there. It's an unwritten rule of using databases with a custom cursor adapter

Answer (score 1):

CursorAdapter always need a column named `_id` you have to provide it for your CursoAdapter, change your Table column id to `_id` or when you are querying from your table make an alias of your `id` column as `_id`

Comment: So i need to change the column name in my database from 'id' to '_id'?

Comment: or you can make an alias from your id column

Answer (score 1):

As Lukasz pointed out, change defines to let `id` be `_id`:

```
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
```

and

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
    "create table if not exists assignments (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + "item VARCHAR not null, litres date );";
```

Comment: I tried running the changes you made but it still didnt work, it says there is no such column?